# Agda: std-lib: List: check that a filtered list is empty

Tags: list, agda, agda-stdlib

I have a function `filter'`:

```
filter' : {A : Set} → (A → Bool) → List A → List A
filter' p []               = l.[]
filter' p (x ∷ xs) with (p x)
...                | true  = x l.∷ filter' p xs
...                | false = filter' p xs
```

and a function `DeleteNat`:

```
DeleteNat : (List ℕ) → ℕ → (List ℕ)
DeleteNat nats id = filter' (λ n → not (n ≡ᵇ id)) nats
```

where `_≡ᵇ_` is:

```
open import Agda.Builtin.Nat public
  using () renaming (_==_ to _≡ᵇ_)
```

and would like to show that after applying `DeleteNat`, there remains no natural number equal to the id in the `List`:

```
DeleteNatRemoveNatWithId :
  (nats : List ℕ) (id : ℕ) →
    filter' (λ n → n ≡ᵇ id) (DeleteNat nats id) ≡ l.[]
DeleteNatRemoveNatWithId []       id         = refl
DeleteNatRemoveNatWithId (x ∷ xs) id with x ≡ᵇ id
...                                  | true  = DeleteNatRemoveNatWithId xs id
...                                  | false = {!  !}
```

I'm unsure how to continue at `{!  !}`. I get a hunch that it should be done using `cong`.

Using `C-c C-.` I see that I need to satisfy this type:

```
(filter' (λ n → n ≡ᵇ id) (x List.∷ filter' (λ n → not (n ≡ᵇ id)) xs) | x ≡ᵇ id) ≡ List.[]
```

I guess I need a way to somehow get the `x List.∷`  into the second argument of the first `filter'`.

Could I get a hint as to how to advance here? Is my assumption about using `cong` wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`filter' ... (x ∷ filter' ... xs) | x ≡ᵇ id)` means that the evaluation of
this function is stuck on the test `x ≡ᵇ id`.

To have it reduce, you would typically use `with x ≡ᵇ id`. But you've already
done that! Yes, but the `with` you used targeted the *inner* `filter` that was
stuck at the time. Once it got unstuck, it computed enough to emit `x ∷ _` and
that got the outer `filter` stuck on the second test (that happens to be equal
to the first one).

The idiomatic way to deal with this is via the [`inspect` idiom](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/README.Inspect.html)
that will allow you to, in a single `with`, get your hands on not only the
result of `x ≡ᵇ id` but also a proof that the result was computed from this
expression. Once you reach the point where the outer `filter` is stuck, you
can simply `rewrite` by this equation and you should then be able to see
the function compute just enough that it will be possible to call the
induction hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks @gallais, I had no idea `filter' ... (x ∷ filter' ... xs) | x ≡ᵇ id)` meant the evaluation got stuck. That's enlightening. When you say I can use `inspect` with in a single `with` what does that look like? I saw `plus-eq-with m n with m + n | inspect (m +_) n` and `filter p (x ∷ xs) with inspect (p x)`. Does the latter case here refer to using a single `with` and the former case refers to having two `with`? Thanks!

Comment: Basing myself on the `README-inspect`, I tried `DeleteNatRemoveNatWithId (x ∷ xs) id with (x ≡ᵇ id) | inspect (id ≡ᵇ_) x
... | true  | P.[ eq ] = DeleteNatRemoveNatWithId xs id
... | false | P.[ eq ] rewrite eq = {!   !}` but now still get the same type for `{!   !}`: `(filter' (λ n → n ≡ᵇ id)
       (x List.∷ filter' (λ n → not (n ≡ᵇ id)) xs)
       | x ≡ᵇ id)
      ≡ List.[]`

Comment: You wrote `inspect (id ≡ᵇ_) x` which records the result of `id ≡ᵇ x` but you want the result of `x ≡ᵇ id`